# No cache for specific Symfony2 TWIG page

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

i want to disable a [twig] cache for an specific Action response on Symfony2?

Is a solution to do this.

I'm  not sure if I will add on response next header response will be not cached

### 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate' ??

Comment: Do you want to disable exactly `twig` cache (PHP class cache) or you just need to disable cache for response (HTTP cache)?

Comment: I want to disable exactly twig cache for specific twig page

Comment: Did I answer on your question? Uo can mark my answer as right.

Comment: I will test it, temporarily we disabled global cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable your `auto_reload` option on `Twig_Environment`. You can read about it here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html

To make it with minimal efforts (and with no affect to other rendering operations) I recommend you to change this option at the moment when you want to render your Action response:

```
$twig = $this->get('twig');
$twig->enableAutoReload();
$twig->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Test:index.html.twig', $parameters);
```

It will ignore cache for all twig templates that are rendered after `$twig->enableAutoReload();`